# How to perform Gray's test with R package tidycmprsk for competing risk data

Tags: r, survival-analysis, chi-squared

I have survival data with competing risk (censored 0, relaps 1, death 2) and I want to use Grey's test to check the difference between groups of a variable rh (categories 0, 1 and 2). This is my data:

```
> surv_data
# A tibble: 344 × 4
           ID        time_to_event          status    rh
          <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl> <fct> 
 1            1             61.2                 0 PHLF 0
 2            2              6.53                1 PHLF 0
 3           10            109.                  0 PHLF 0
 4           15             15.5                 2 PHLF 2
 5           19              4.97                0 PHLF 0
 6           20             17.9                 1 PHLF 1
 7           22             61.7                 1 PHLF 0
 8           23             74.0                 2 PHLF 0
 9           26             67.9                 2 PHLF 1
10           27             46.8                 2 PHLF 0
# ℹ 389 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

What is the difference between Gray's test in tidycmprsk::tbl_cuminc and tidycmprsk::cuminc. I get different outputs.

I tried the following below, and I don't understand why I get different outputs of the tests. Hpw should i interpret the results and what is the right way to do Gray's test?

1)

```
tidycmprsk::cuminc(Surv(time_to_event, status) ~ rh, data = surv_data) %>% 
  tidycmprsk::tbl_cuminc(
    times =  c(6, 12, 24), label_header = "**Month {time}**"
  ) %>% 
  add_p() %>% 
  add_n()
```

and I get output:

```
`
Characteristic  N   Month 6       Month 12          Month 24    p-value1
rh  399                                               0.07
    rh 0        32% (15%, 33%)  45% (39%, 50%)  62% (36%, 65%)  
    rh 1        23% (9%, 28%)   37% (21%, 53%)  46% (38%, 68%)  
    rh  2       28% (12%, 42%)  27% (15%, 63%)  38% (21%, 55%)  
1 Gray’s Test
`
```

2. 

```
tidycmprsk::cuminc(ftime=surv_data$time_to_event, fstatus=surv_data$status, group=surv_data$rh, cencode=0)
```

and I get output:

```
`
Tests:
                      stat           pv df
Censored          2.20168  1.176649e-01  2
Relapse           5.75114  2.376312e-01  2
Death            28.383626 3.183201e-09  2
`
```

3. 

```
tidycmprsk::cuminc(Surv(time_to_event, status) ~ rh, data = surv_data, cencode=0)
```

and I get output:

```
`
• Tests
outcome            statistic   df     p.value    
Relapse            4.31        2.00   0.07      
Death              32.3        2.00   <0.001   
`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got yourself into difficulty because you are mixing `tidycmprsk` and `cmprsk`. Both of these packages have a function called `cuminc()`. Your second code snippet is:

```r
tidycmprsk::cuminc(ftime=surv_data$time_to_event, fstatus=surv_data$status, group=surv_data$rh, cencode=0)
```

However, the [docs](https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/tidycmprsk/reference/cuminc.html) for `tidycmprsk::cuminc()` indicate it either takes a formula or a parameter called `x`. The parameters you are providing (`ftime`, `fstatus` and so on) are the arguments for [`cmprsk::cuminc()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cmprsk/versions/2.2-11/topics/cuminc). As all your parameters are named and none of them is `x`, this code will generate an error.

The `tidycmprsk::cuminc()` [source](https://github.com/cran/tidycmprsk/blob/ad69e7958f3ab511632ecacb95e4e9cea1e14e17/R/cuminc.R#L86) calls `cmprsk::cuminc()` under the hood, so once you resolve your argument names you will get the same results. Here's an example with the `trial` data built-in to the `tidycmprsk` package, using both approaches.

### `tidycmprsk`

Note that here I am using `death_cr` as the status variable. As the docs state:

> The status variable must be a factor, where the first level indicates the observation was censored, and subsequent levels are the competing events.

Make sure that your data is in this form.

```r
library(tidycmprsk)

tidy_model <- tidycmprsk::cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) |>
    tbl_cuminc(times = c(6, 12, 24)) |>
    add_p() |>
    add_n()

data.frame(tidy_model$table_body[1, c("statistic", "p.value")])
#   statistic   p.value
# 1   1.98847 0.1585009
```

### `cmprsk`

This is the equivalent using `cmprsk`. Again as we are using the factor variable `death_cr` as the status, we can provide `cencode = "censor"`, i.e. a character vector indicating the label of the factor level associated with being censored (rather than `cencode = 0` in your question).

```r
gray_model <- cmprsk::cuminc(
    ftime = trial$ttdeath,
    fstatus = trial$death_cr,
    group = trial$trt,
    cencode = "censor"
)

gray_model$Tests
#                          stat        pv df
# death from cancer  1.98847032 0.1585009  1
# death other causes 0.08856723 0.7660066  1
```

You can see that the p-value and statistic are the same.

### A general comment on namespaces

Where packages have overlapping functions (these two also have `crr()` in common), there are various approaches. In my example I loaded `tidycmprsk` with `library()`, and called `cmprsk` functions explicitly with `::`. This is about the minimum you should do in these cases. The [Google R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.html#qualifying-namespaces) in fact suggests that:

> Users should explicitly qualify namespaces for all external functions.

Of course this advice makes more sense for a huge company with a massive codebase than a single researcher who may not generally face a huge risk of namespace collisions.

Another approach which has many advantages is to use the [`box`](https://github.com/klmr/box) package. This allows you to (amongst other things) explicitly import the functions you want to use from specific packages rather than importing all functions from a package, which `library()` does.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this! :) Is it important that status death_cr and the group variable trt are of type factor?

Comment: @anso_s yes if you're using `tidycmprsk`